# Custom Wordpress theme - fancybox not working?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, fancybox, fancybox-2

(Wordpress 3.5.1)

Hi, in functions.php I've included following:

```
function add_lightbox_cys() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'fancybox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/lightbox/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'lightbox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/lightbox/js/jquery.lightbox.js', array('fancybox'), false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'lightbox-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/lightbox/css/jquery.fancybox.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_lightbox_cys');
```

and then created the lightbox.js with following code:

`(function($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
})(jQuery);`

now in the wordpress theme twentytwelve which came with wordpress this actually works opening pictures in a fancybox.

But when I try this in my own custom made theme it does not trigger the fancybox at all.

here the link to the site: http://goo.gl/y6qfb

can anybody help me?

Comment: you seem to have a lot of things to fix ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with this checklist (may not be everthing) :

1). Your page doesn't have a proper `DOCTYPE` (don't ask me why), you can fix that in your new theme template.

2). You don't seem to be using lightbox so remove this reference

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'lightbox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/lightbox/js/jquery.lightbox.js', array('fancybox'), false, true );
```

3). You are loading fancybox css stylesheet as **script**, hence the error

```
Timestamp: 31/03/2013 1:14:48 PM
Error: SyntaxError: syntax error
Source File: http://jarsis.de/tground/wp-content/themes/cys/inc/lightbox/css/jquery.fancybox.css?ver=3.5.1
Line: 2
Source Code: .fancybox-wrap,
```

... so you would need to replace this line :

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'lightbox-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/lightbox/css/jquery.fancybox.css' );
```

by this :

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'lightbox-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/lightbox/css/jquery.fancybox.css' );
```

... but it depends on how you registered the new stylesheet.

4). You may need to wrap your fancybox initialization code inside the `.ready()` method like :

```
(function($) { 
  $(function(){
     $(".fancybox").fancybox();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: thx for your help. 2) actually solved the whole problem. idk why i typed jquery.lightbox.js when it was actually just lightbox.js... for the other stuff I probably was just too blind to see but I had it all right in the twentytwelve theme. thx alot :D

Answer (score 0):

Firebug reports a 404 for http://jarsis.de/tground/wp-content/themes/cys/inc/lightbox/js/jquery.lightbox.js?ver=3.5.1, indicating that the Lightbox js doesn't get loaded. I suppose that might explain the problem.

Firebug also reports a syntax error which is a bit hard to interpret, but has something to do with ".fancybox-wrap"

Comment: thank you very much :) Your answer and the one from jfk solved the problems for me. again thanks alot :D